# SQL Output to get only last 7 days output while using convert on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the below SQL Query to get the data from a table for the last 7 days.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   emp 
WHERE  date >= (SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), Getdate() - 6, 101)) 
       AND date <= (SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), Getdate(), 101)) 
ORDER  BY date
```

The data in the table is also holding the last year data.

Problem is I am getting the output with Date column as

```
10/11/2013
10/12/2012
10/12/2013
10/13/2012
10/13/2013
10/14/2012
10/14/2013
10/15/2012
10/15/2013
10/16/2012
10/16/2013
10/17/2012
10/17/2013
```

I don't want the output of `2012` year. Please suggest on how to change the query to get the data for the last 7 days of this year.

Comment: What is the data structure of this table?

Comment: I made a simple sQLFiddle, I can't reproduce your results.  What am I missing?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d1e4/3

Comment: I don't think you need the `AND` statement
if the date is more than or equal to `today - 6` then that will always be enough. Unless, of course you can this is populated with future dates...

Comment: your issue is you are comparing varchars in your where statement convert the date to a datetime rather than the other way round

Comment: I don't know, I tried it with varchar values in the table, it still worked correctly for me.  Wierd...

Comment: @Andrew change the col1 to a `VARCHAR` ;) and populate with enough data... `values ('11/11/2013'), ('10/11/2012'), ('10/15/2012')`

Comment: Ah, you're right, once I got past 2 rows in the table, it started happening.  I could dance round it if I cast the column in the table to date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of converting a `date` to a `varchar` and comparing a `varchar` against a `varchar`. Convert the `varchar` to a `datetime` and then compare that way.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM   
    emp 
WHERE   
    convert(datetime, date, 101)  BETWEEN (Getdate() - 6) AND Getdate() 
ORDER BY 
    date
```

Answer (score 5):

Why convert to varchar when processing dates?  Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @7DaysAgo DATETIME = DATEADD(day,-7,@Now);

SELECT * 
FROM   emp 
WHERE  date BETWEEN @7DaysAgo AND @Now
ORDER  BY date
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since you have done the same thing. @7DaysAgo should be `-7`. And use `day` instead `d` to make it more clear.

Comment: @mayabelle I think the reason the OP is comparing `VARCHAR`s is because they are storing a date as a `VARCHAR` which is why when doing the compare he is getting invalid dates.

Comment: @Kaf Thanks, that was a typo. Now fixed.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel Thank you for clarifying. In that case my suggestion would have been to store the date as a date...

Answer (score -1):

Use this, simply.

```
 Select columnname
        from tablename
            WHERE datecolumn> dateadd(day,-7,GETDATE())
```